# event.target is taking react child components separately

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a menu box in my react app and I show when I click on show menu button and hiding it if menu its open. I want to hide menu if I click outside the menu

```
class MenuButton extends Component {
 constructor (props) {
  super (props)
  this.state = {showMenu: false}
  this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this)
 }

 toggleMenu () {
   let showMenu = !this.state.showMenu
   this.setState({showMenu})
 }

 componentDidMount () {
  window.addEventListner('click', e => {
   if (e.target !== document.getElementById('menu-div') {
    this.setState({showMenu: false})
   }
  })
 }

 render () {} {
  return (
   <div>
    <button onClick={this.toggleMenu}>Menu</button>
    {this.state.showMenu ? <div id='menu-div><Menu /></div> : null}
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

and my Menu Component has many child Components

```
const Menu = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Component1/>
      <Component2/>
      <Component3/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

but clicking on these child components close my menu as event.target is giving different node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use `getElementById` nor search elements in the `DOM`.  This is not the "React Way" of doing things and it's considered a bad practice.
Instead use the [refs API that react provides](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and grab a reference to the node.
You can add event listener of `mousedown` and check if the `ref` contains the target, if not then it means you are outside the `ref` (the menu in your case). So all is left is to set the state to close it.

Here is a running snippet of your code with the implementation i mentioned:

```js
class MenuButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showMenu: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleOutsideClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.handleOutsideClick);
  }

  toggleMenu = () => {
    let showMenu = !this.state.showMenu;
    this.setState({ showMenu });
  };

  handleOutsideClick = event => {
    if (this.menuRef && !this.menuRef.contains(event.target)) {
      this.setState({ showMenu: false });
    }
  };

  setRef = ref => {
    this.menuRef = ref;
  };

  render() {
    const { showMenu } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleMenu}>Menu</button>
        {<Menu className={`${!showMenu && "hide"}`} setRef={this.setRef} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { setRef, className } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={`menu ${className}`} ref={setRef}>
        <div>comp 1</div>
        <div>comp 2</div>
        <div>comp 3</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MenuButton />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.hide{
  display: none;
}

.menu{
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```